# Kendo UI Scheduler scrolls up automatically in IE when click slot

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, scroll, scheduler, splitter

I'm using Kendo UI Scheduler component with a vertical Splitter component.

The screen is separated vertically through a splitter component, in the top panel there's a scheduler component and in the bottom panel, there is a custom form.

When I click a slot the splitter scrolls up automatically. That doesn't happen with Chrome.

Does any body can help me?

UPDATE>

Here is my code: https://github.com/SebastianGerard/kendoui/blob/master/Agenda.html

I can't select an area of the scheduler at the bottom.

UPDATE2>

Here a video: http://youtu.be/La3gAJmvvyA

Comment: We've had lots of issues with this scheduler within custom regions. The state of the controller is most comfortable when it's the only thing in the DOM. Expect the unexpected. Log tickets with Telerik...and if you're really wanting help, get a fiddle of some sort started...your environment is no good in just words.

Comment: Yes, you are right but do you have any idea why that could be happening? Post all my code would be imposible, it's very extensive.

Comment: it happens because of all the DOM elements being manipulated on the kendo side. they've got so much going on with the component that it requires lots of attention if you're trying to put it in your own environment. the answer is 'there is no answer'...at this point, you'll also need to be careful, for any future release will most likely cause any overrides you put into play now to fail then...

Comment: if you don't set up a mock-environment you can't even get valid support from Telerik...so if it's something you really need solved, then you'll need to create it...you can even put up a 'demo' environment on GitHub and use that as your example

Comment: https://github.com/SebastianGerard/kendoui/blob/master/Agenda.html Example

Comment: http://youtu.be/La3gAJmvvyA Video

Answer (score 0):

This is related to browser specific behavior where when given element is focused (the scheduler needs to focus it's wrapper in order to enable keyboard navigation) and it's not fully visible in current view port the browser triggers "Scroll into view" action. This action is not preventable and scrolls the page to the top of the focused element. The best solution in this case is to simply reduce the Scheduler size in order to be fully visible inside the view port. For example of such solution you can check the following demo in Kendo UI documentation:

- [Scheduler: Dynamic calculation of the widget height](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/dynamic-calc-of-height)

Answer (score 0):

There are some workaround that will help to fix this issue.

1.Initialize in Scheduler dataBinding callback contentScrollHandler() which will listen to change scheduler scroll position and keep it.

```
function contentScrollHandler(){
        var _this = $(this);
        clearTimeout(scrollHandlerTimeout);
        scrollHandlerTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
             saveLastSCrollPosition(_this.scrollTop(););
        }, 150);
}
```

2.Restore last saved scroll position inside Scheduler change callback.

```
function restoreLastPosition(){
    var scrollPosition = getLastScrollPosition();
    $scheduler.find(SCROLLABLE_TABLE).animate({scrollTop: scrollPosition });
}
```

All time when you are scrolling contentScrollHandler() save scheduler scroll last position. When you are trying to resize\move scheduler event then scheduler at once scroll to top visible part of focused event. Then scheduler fire change callback and restoreLastPosition() scroll to last saved scroll position. 
Users will not be able to see scroll jumping. And so all will be alright and nothing will be jumping.

Answer (score 0):

From [Telerik Docs:](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/troubleshoot/troubleshooting)

Widget Jumps on Focus

When widget navigation is enabled, the widget wrapper becomes a focusable element. On click, the browser focuses it and preforms the so called scroll-into-view action. If the widget exceeds the height/width of the view-port, then it scrolls the page automatically. The goal is to position the focusable element at the top left corner of the view-port. During this process, actions like double click, drag or resize would not be available due to the movement of the page.

*The page re-positioning is a default browser behavior, which cannot be prevented nor modified.*

To avoid this behavior, choose either of the available options:

- Disable widget's navigation, if it is not needed in your business
  case.
- Size the widget to the view-port dimensions.